# How to set BigTextStyle in GCM Java Message Builder

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending Push Notifications to my Android app using the GCM Message Builder. I am building the notification like this:

```
Message message = new Message.Builder()
        .collapseKey("message")
        .timeToLive(3)
        .delayWhileIdle(true)
        .addData("message", pushMessage)
        .addData("title", "My test title")
        .build();
```

My question is if I have long push notification text how to be able to expand the notification displayed in the tray?

I am trying to use BigTextStyle but I can't find a way with GCM jar?

Comment: You do that in the client (Android app) code that displays the notification, not in the server that sends the message.

Comment: Ahh! And I am using Ionic Framework so phonegap push in the app - I will google thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this where you get your notification in GCM Intent Service.. Title and Text will be data from the Bundle you get from GCM parameter.

```
mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
.bigText("Text").setBigContentTitle("Title"));
```